# My Audio Driver is Bugged and I can't seem to fix it or update it no matter what I do

Tags: windows

I've just bought a second-hand pc (windows 10 64-bit, pretty sure). I connected my Headset to the audio jack and it came up with 4 options:

- line-in
- mic-in
- headphones
- speaker-out

I couldn't find the headset option. It was later that I found out my audio driver was outdated, and I figured this was the problem.
So I went and tried to manually install/update a new driver file from the internet (I got it from the intel website).

Once I did this, I went into the device manager and right-clicked Realtek(R) Audio:
[image: Once I did this, I went into the device manager and right-clicked Realtek(R) Audio]
Then I clicked update driver, and then I clicked Browse my computer for drivers.

Here I ran into my first problem, I pasted the driver's location into the search bar and then it came up with this:
[image: It said it was already set to Realtek High Definition Audio but on Device manager, it still says that I only have Realtek(R) Audio]

It said it was already set to Realtek High Definition Audio but on Device manager, it still says that I only have Realtek(R) Audio
This really confused me so I went "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer" and I chose my version. Then It said it was installed, but when I exit out of the window, I see that nothing has changed. The driver is still the old version and nothing has happened.

The second thing I did was use the .exe file that came with the driver package I installed. (it was called Setup.exe). I followed the instructions, restarted the pc, watched it "Update Windows" and then I was back on the home screen. I checked my audio on my taskbar, very briefly, it was configured to my new driver, but then it switched back to the old driver. (The 'Realtek(R) Audio' driver).

I have no clue what to do now and am in dire need of help.

Comment: *"...it came up with 4 options ... headphones ... I couldn't find the headset option"* do you mean a headset with a microphone? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770919/edit) the question to clarify this, and include the make/model of the headset in question. You can find your Win version by going *Start button > Settings > System > About*, then under *Device Type* see *System Type*.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? Are you absolutely certain it has a headset socket, rather than separate mic/speaker/headphone sockets? A picture of the socket field would be useful. You might need something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Jelly-Tang-Headphone-Splitter-Smartphone-Black/dp/B074N6XLHT/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=mic+and+headphone+adapter&qid=1677489677&sr=8-4) [random internet search, not a recommendation].

Comment: Perhaps you need an adapter from headset plug to mic & speaker. There seem to be two standards CTIA and OMTP. Here is one for CTIA https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0727NBHBV?language=en_GB